# All users can log into SharePoint 2010 site even though I removed Domain users from all groups

Tags: permissions

I have a SharePoint 2010 site that had Domain users in a group with read permissions. I did not want to allow all users in AD to be able to log into this SharePoint site so I removed Domain users from that group but I find all users can still login. I made sure Domain users was not set in any other group. Is there some other place I missing that could have Domain users set?

Comment: did you 'check permissions' for 'Domain Users'? site settings - site permissions - check permissions. what does it say?

Comment: There are other ways they could be accessing the site. Do you have anonymous access disabled? Are you using authenticated users anywhere? Find an account that you don't want to have access and check permissions to see how they're able to get to the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you checked all the SharePoint Groups for your domain group an then there could be at least three additional ways these users could have access:

- You have the Authenticated Users group in one of your SharePoint Groups
- You have Anonymous Access configured
- You have an AD group configured for access in the Web Application's Permission Policies